# Why does AG Grid version 29+ break the TranslatePipe output?

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular, ngx-translate

I would like to know **why** an upgrade from AG Grid (Angular) from version 28 to version 29 or 30 (latest at the time of writing) necessitates the following change to our code...

I am upgrading dependency versions on an existing Angular (v15) project. It uses the AG Grid (community edition, old version: v28, which I am trying to upgrade to the newest: v30). This project is i18n'ed for a number of languages, so it depends on the @ngx-translate (v14) functionality to provide text in the appropriate language. Specifically, for the AG Grid's [overlay templates](https://ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/overlays/), this uses the [TranslatePipe](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#5-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive) as show in the code snippet below.

On Ag Grid v28 the code looks like this:

```
<ag-grid-angular
  ...
  overlayLoadingTemplate="{{'loading' | translate}}"
  overlayNoRowsTemplate="{{'no_records' | translate}}"
</ag-grid-angular>
```

When upgrading the AG Grid versions:

```
    "ag-grid-angular": "^30.0.2",
    "ag-grid-community": "^30.0.2",
```

... suddenly the data is simply not displayed in the grid any more (yes, I ascertained that there is row data). The console log also displays this (quite unhelpful) error message:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting '__agComponent')

with a stack trace.

Playing around, I found that adding random text, or a useful HTML tag, outside the handlebar mustache suddenly makes the grid data appear (and the console log error disappear).

On Ag Grid v29 and 30 this code works (note added `<p>` tags):

```
<ag-grid-angular
  ...
  overlayLoadingTemplate="<p>{{'loading' | translate}}"
  overlayNoRowsTemplate="<p>{{'no_records' | translate}}"
</ag-grid-angular>
```

I am puzzled because the v28 code *does* provide valid HTML to the `overlay...Template` attributes (plain text is valid HTML, not so?). **If anyone can shed light on the reason behind this change, or point me to the documentation where this change is highlighted, I would be much obliged.** Or is there a more obscure reason involving the `TranslatePipe`? I am pretty puzzled.